# Python Reading a file print several information

Tags: python

I got the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys

#read information
f = open ("/home/ibrahim/Desktop/Test.list")
text = f.read()

#show existing companys
Companyname = text.split("\n")
print Companyname

#User chooses a company he wants to know more about
raw_input('\n<Wählen Sie die Firma Ihrer Wahl aus um die Informationen anzuzeigen.>\n\n<Geben Sie die Firmenspezifische Zahl ein und b$

#Companyspecific information is getting revealed
```

The **Test.list** looks like this

```
(1)Chef,1965,10
(2)Fisher,1932,20
(3)Gardener,1998,5
```

My aim is, that the user of this program can choose a specific Company he wants to find out more about. For example, the year this company started and the number of employees 
**Example:** **Companyname = Chef**, **year the company started = 1965** and **number of employees = 10**
I don't want to print more than the company's name, because the information in the future will contain more than just the founding year and the number of employees.

Edit: Sucks that I can't accept every answer and can't up-vote anybody because I really want to :S I appreciate every help I got from you and the guy who edited my post so it looked a bit better ^^

Comment: please format the code properly for better readability. see - [how to format code blocks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: yes I am sorry :/ I was confused as well when I saw that ^^ I thank you very much for the thread "how to format code blocks" :)

Comment: I'd recommend using `splitlines()` instead of `split('\n')` since it's both more readable and more robust for Windows systems which also use the `\r` (carriage return) character with the `\n` (line break character). It's almost always better to use standard library code instead of re-writing it yourself :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an working example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

for line in open('data.txt'):
    company, year, number_of_employee = line.split(',')
    print "Company: %s" % company
```

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

you can do:

```
info = text.split("\n")
CompanyName = [inf.split(')')[1].split(',')[0] for inf in info]
```

Comment: hm :/ it shows me this error                                        Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ibrahim/Desktop/Testtesten.py", line 15, in <module>
    CompanyName = info.split(')')[1].split(',')[0]
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: Probably should have been `CompanyName = [i.split... for i in info]`

Answer (score 1):

How about using a regular expression to find the several parts?

```
import re
with open("Test.list") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        m = re.match(r'\((\d)+\)([^,]+),(\d+),(\d+)', line)
        print m.groups()
```

The first group is the ID `(\d)+`, the second the name `([^,]+)` (everything except a comma), the third the year `(\d+)` and the fourth the number of employees `(\d+)`.

Of course, if it's okay to have the company name together with the ID you can just as well just use `line.split(',')` or `csv`.

Comment: this works perfectly !!! thanks :) I try to understand what you wrote now and I appreciate it that you are explaining it as well ! thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is an other example, more efficient.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# virtualenv ~/.virtualens/company_reader
# source ~/.virtualenvs/company_reader/bin/activate
# pip install prettytable
# python reader.py
import re 
from collections import namedtuple

# PrettyTable is a tool to format a list of elements with an elegant table.
import prettytable

Company = namedtuple('Company', ['identifier', 'name', 'year', 'nbr_employee'])

company_name = raw_input('Enter the company: ').lower()

# The regexp
pattern_str = r"\((?P<identifier>\d+)\)(?P<name>\w+),(?P<year>\d+),(?P<nbr_employee>\d+)"
pattern = re.compile(pattern_str)

companies = []

# TODO: add a argument parser
# docopt is a correct solution for this purpose
for line in open('data.txt'):
    matching = pattern.match(line)
    # if there is no matching, continue on the next line
    if matching is None:
        continue
    company = Company(*matching.groups())
    if company.name.lower() == company_name:
        companies.append(company)

if not companies:
    print "Sorry, there is no result"
else:
    pt = prettytable.PrettyTable(['Identifier', 'Name', 'Year', 'Number of Employee'])
    pt.align['Identifier'] = 'l'
    pt.align['Name'] = 'l'
    pt.align['Number of Employee'] = 'r'

    for company in companies:
         pt.add_row([company.identifier, company.name, company.year, company.nbr_employee])

    print pt
```

Comment: thank you for this code ! I downloaded "prettytable" but I already don't know what to enter when it says 'Enter the company: ' I am a real newbie in Python and it would be awesome if you could tell me what to type in here exactly ^^ thanks :)

Comment: "Enter the company" asks you to insert a company from your file.

Comment: For the code, we use the pattern matching with the regexp, and we iterate over all the lines, to find the right line. If we find a matching line, we add it into a list.  At the end of your file, we will show the result under the form of a table.

Comment: yes I am sorry ! I failed to write the path right :7 I forgot about a letter... but now it tells me: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ibrahim/Desktop/TestTest.py", line 37, in <module>
    pt.align['Identifier'] = 'l'
AttributeError: PrettyTable instance has no attribute 'align'

Comment: Here is a gist with the original code. but I don't have this problem with my code:  https://gist.github.com/matrixise/6494354

Answer (score 0):

You will done it with csv reader. http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

```
>>> import csv
>>> list={}
>>> with open('/home/ibrahim/Desktop/Test.list', 'rb') as csvfile:
...     spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
...     for name,year,number in spamreader:
...         id,name = name.split(')',1)
...         list[name] = {'year':year,'number':number,'name':name}
>>> name = raw_input('Enter company name')
>>> print '{name} started at {year} and has {number} workers'.format(**list[name])
```