# python saving information from text data

Tags: python

this is my Code

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import re

#read information

f = open ("/home/ibrahim/Desktop/Test.list")

text = f.read()

#show existing companys

for line in open('/home/ibrahim/Desktop/Test.list'):
    company, founding_year, number_of_employee = line.split(',')
    print "Company: %s" % company

#User chooses a company he wants to know more about

CompanyIndex = raw_input('\n<Choose a company you want to know more about.>\n\n<Insert a companyspecific-number and press "Enter" .>\n')

#Companyspecific information is getting revealed

if CompanyIndex == '1':
        print #company1,founding_year1,number_of_employee2
elif CompanyIndex == '2':
        print #company2,founding_year2,number_of_employee2
elif CompanyIndex == '3':
        print #company3,founding_year3,number_of_employee3
else:
        print 'Your input is not correct..'
```

My aim is that the user of this program can choose a specific Company he wants to find out more about, like for example the year this company started and the number of employees Example: Companyname = Chef, year the company started = 1965 and number of employees = 10 I don't want to print more than the company's name, because the information in the future will contain more than just the founding year and the number of employees ;) it would be pretty confusing to see so much information ^^ Now my Problem is, that I do not know how to save the Information I received about the company and how to print those out in this block:

```
if CompanyIndex == '1':
        print #company1,founding_year1,number_of_employee2
elif CompanyIndex == '2':
        print #company2,founding_year2,number_of_employee2
elif CompanyIndex == '3':
        print #company3,founding_year3,number_of_employee3
else:
        print 'Your input is not correct..'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building upon your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18653909/1639625), you can extend your `for` loop to store the company data in a dictionary:

```
companies = {}
for line in open('/home/ibrahim/Desktop/Test.list'):
    # line is "(Number)Name,Year,Employees"
    company, founding_year, number_of_employee = line.split(',')
    # company is "(Number)Name"
    number, name = company.split(")")
    number = number[1:] # trim '('
    companies[number] = (name, founding_year, number_of_employee)
    print "Company: %s" % company
```

Now, you an get the information from the dictionary, using the number as key:

```
if CompanyIndex in companies:
    name, founding_year, number_of_employee = companies[CompanyIndex]
    # print stuff
else:
    print 'Your input is not correct..'
```

Comment: Awesome !!! it works :D thank you very much I still try to understand how you did that and try to get your mindset but it is working :) sorry I am kind of new to python

Answer (score 1):

Add this into the mix:

```
# To store info from the text file:
companyDB = []

# Read from file for existing companies

for line in open('/home/ibrahim/Desktop/Test.list'):
    company, founding_year, number_of_employee = line.split(',')
    print "Company: %s" % company

    # Store it locally
    companyDB.append((company, founding_year, number_of_employee))
```

Now when the user selects any number:

```
print companyDB[companyIndex - 1] # Since your first line will be item number 0 in the list
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use list or dictionary

`comapnay_data = [dict(zip(('company', 'founding_year', 'number_of_employee'), line.split(','))) for line in open()]`

which would make your indexing through 0.

Or

`company_data = {no: dict(zip(('company', 'founding_year', 'number_of_employee'), line.split(','))) for no, line in enumerate(open(), start=1)}`